# How make in Python a grid with perfect square cell?

Tags: arcpy

I have points layer in wgs84 4326 (longitude: ±180, latitude: ±90). I want make a grid with square cell to count how many points are inside a single cell. In python, I make a contour points of the grid (from a start point I use the same step value in degres for longitude and latitude) and after I use in Arcgis the tool to make line vertical and horizontal line and finally obtain a grid with square cell. If I measure the two side of a single cell, I see that they have different value but I can see that are square. This is normal due to the projection in use. My intent is to have perfect square cell for the wgs84 3857, so which are the steps to make this grid? One solution is to use a different steps for longitude and latitude in wgs84 4326 but I don't understand which is the correct step value to use. Second option maybe is to convert the contour points of my grid in wgs84 3857 and create the step for longitude and latitude but again I don't understand which is the correct value for the step.  My zone of interest isn't the entire world. The latitude actually lie within the range of 0 to +60 and longitude lie within the range of -30 to +60. I work in python with longitude: ±180 and latitude: ±90 , so for me is sufficient find a formula (for my zone of interest above) that give me a good value approximation of the longitude step in degrees after I decide in latitude degrees the cell size

Comment: You've posed a question which is impossible to answer. It is not possible to represent far-north/far-south data in a Mercator projection.  In reality, you can choose between various rules for "square-ish" polygons that change in proportion at every latitude, but come close to being actually square, or you can choose for square-looking polygons that are very much not square.

Comment: @Vince my zone of interest isn't the entire world. The latitude actually lie within the range of 0 to +60 and longitude lie within the range of -30 to +60. I work in python with longitude: ±180 and latitude: ±90 , so for me is sufficient find a formula (for my zone of interest above) that give me a good value
approximation of the longitude step in degrees after I decide in latitude degrees the cell size.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to clarify details like this. Making significant changes to the question in comments is unfair to those volunteers who might try to help.

Comment: @Vince I edit the original question by put the new details

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could try to set up your environment so that your output coordinate system is in WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere, either in your environments when you run a tool like Create Fishnet, or setting env.outputCoordinateSystem to that spatial reference in Python.